# After changing the default folder, Windows Explorer now only accesses this folder on any shortcut

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/70161/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-default-folder-for-windows-explorer) asking how to set my default folder in Windows Explorer.

Changing the registry key worked perfectly...so I thought. Now when I try to double-click a shortcut in Explorer it automatically just takes me right back to the default folder instead of opening the shortcut.

I can right-click the shortcut and select Open and this works, but double-clicking runs the Explore command, which is where the problem is apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to undo the change you did to the registry, and rather make yourself a desktop icon to launch the Explorer to the wanted default directory:

> %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n, /e,
>   /select, "directory"

You may also either drag this icon to the Quick Launch area, or use a product such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to launch it with a hotkey.

Comment: The only problem with downloading a 3rd party app to do this is that my company has to sign off on installations before I can run them. It would be way cooler if I could just get this registry change to work correctly. Is there any way?

Comment: explorer.exe is Windows Explorer by Microsoft. No 3rd party software is involved.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me clarify - I meant that to launch with a hotkey requires 3rd party software. I use Win+E to open Windows Explorer constantly, so I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: Launch with a hotkey doesn't require 3rd-party. Only if you insist on a Windows-specific key such as Win-E.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @harrymc about undoing the Registry hack.  If you look at your other question, I suggested using AutoHotkey to create a *new* hotkey (Win+w, for example) to launch a Windows Explorer window for the directory you access most frequently, and *leave Win+e untouched*.  I even [included a script](https://superuser.com/questions/70161/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-default-folder-for-windows-explorer/70203#70203) that will do what you need (on Win+w, instead of Win+e).

Comment: A couple of questions on this:

1) I forgot to backup the registry before I made the change (yeah yeah, I know) so can you tell me what the Default key is supposed to read, please?

2) Before I throw in the towel, is there any way to alter the way shortcuts are handled in Explorer so that they open the link instead of just opening the default Explorer window?