# Can I change the location that Windows key + E opens to (Windows 7 specific)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to set up a default folder for Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/70161/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-default-folder-for-windows-explorer)

I really like opening new Windows Explorer windows via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> but I'm not a fan of it opening to `Computer`. Can I change that in the registry or something? Looking for a Windows 7 solution

Comment: Looks like this may be a duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/70161/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-default-folder-for-windows-explorer

Comment: just gonna put this right here too since it solved my question http://www.mydigitallife.info/trick-to-open-computer-or-documents-as-default-instead-of-libraries-folder-with-windows-explorer-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

I have an [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) script running and added this line:

```
#e::run c:\public
```

and that overrode the system setting. You could put any location in there.

(or any action, really, this **is** autohotkey... :)

Comment: They actually have a page on this: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm

Comment: BTW: which OS do you have?

Comment: win7. looking for a native solution though - trying to avoid adding yet another little utility to keep track of

Answer (score 0):

No, these are not customizable.  You may create another hot key for windows using third party software though, there's a lot out there.

Here's one which may work (maybe, it was a quick google search) https://mysite.uchicago.edu/personal/bsdad_rcarter/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=ec587393-9b2f-46b0-87d6-a594b1e8d383&ID=88