# Windows+E opens "Quick Access" instead opening "Windows explorer" in WIndows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, windows-10

in `Windows 7, 8 & 8.1` I used to use shortcut key combination of `Win+E` to open `Windows Explorer`. But in `Windows 10`, i see that Win+E opens `Quick Access` location by default.

**Is there anyway to set Default Location as `This PC (Windows Explorer)` for `Win+E`.**

ps - I've already visited this links but as you can see non of these addresses `Windows 10`.

[Can I change the location that Windows key + E opens to (Windows 7 specific)?](https://superuser.com/questions/184455/can-i-change-the-location-that-windows-key-e-opens-to-windows-7-specific)

[Is there a way to set up a default folder for Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/70161/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-default-folder-for-windows-explorer)

http://www.mydigitallife.info/trick-to-open-computer-or-documents-as-default-instead-of-libraries-folder-with-windows-explorer-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you click `File` at top left then click `Change Folder and search options`, you can change it to only two options `This PC` or `Quick Access`

Answer (score 2):

It's old but I guess still needed.. So, as illustrated in the picture. 
Open Explorer and go to View -> Options -> General. Change Open File Explorer to This PC. That's all.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternative process with Registry editor::

- Go to this Registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]`.
- Find  the DWORD value **LaunchTo**.
- If you want to set it in *Quick Access* change the registry data **2**
- If you want to set it in *This PC* change the registry data **1**