# Globally set the default folder for Windows Explorer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows 7, how can I set the default folder shown by Windows Explorer when it gets launched with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>?  ([A previous answer here](https://superuser.com/a/70171/142252) explains how to do this with some unspecified version of Windows, but the solution does not work on Windows 7.)

I know that it is possible to change the command line used by the Windows Explorer shortcut in the start menu so that launching this shortcut opens a certain folder.  This is not sufficient for me; I would like to set the default globally, so that Explorer opens a certain folder even when invoked without arguments, or when invoked with the standard <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Other suggestion seem to indicate that you could e.g. use AutoHotkey to setup a binding. Would that be an option? You could also check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/3933/change-starting-location-of-explorer-from-windows-e) which has another approach.

Comment: I don't know what AutoHotKey is. If it can do what I want, then please post it as an answer and I will consider accepting it (particularly if it doesn't involve installing third-party software). Regarding that other answer, it's nonsensical because `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command` is a folder, not a registry key. I tried applying the suggested value to the default key and/or DelegateExecute but this didn't work.

Comment: Every "folder" (key) in the registry has a `(Default)` entry. That is what the answer is concerned with, also look at the second comment on the answer.  [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) is a utility (third-party software) that would allow you to rebind Win+E to some different action. It would catch the keypress and execute something different. It would mean that you'd always have to have the script that does it running. Your original reference actually has an answer that points it out.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, why did you mark this as a duplicate of a question which I specifically referenced as being for a different version of Windows, and whose accepted solution does not work in Windows 7?

Comment: Because the _question_ is a duplicate. Further evidenced by the fact that one answer you've received so far, is one of the answers on the duplicate question. If you'd like different/newer answers, please spend a bit of Rep and place a Bounty on the existing question, instead of just asking it again.

Answer (score 0):

Like seth said, you can use autohotkey which seems to be the only way to complete what you want to achieve. To my knowledge this could work on various windows system so here's what it is and what you need to do as well.

description from their website:

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source scripting language for Windows that
>   allows users to easily create small to complex scripts for all kinds
>   of tasks such as: form fillers, auto-clicking, macros, etc.

You can also remap keys which is what I'll show you.

First, go to www.autohotkey.com and install the app. Then from your desktop, just create a new script (right click, go on new and click on "autohotkey script" and make it a name. Then edit that script and use this code :

```
#w:: ;; Win+w
{
 Run C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /n`, /root`, C:\
}
return
```

Change that c:\ to whatever you want. Also look at these windows explorer settings if you want to further customize your explorer:

- /e      List (explorer) view, Show large icons if missing (Open view)
- /root   Sets the top level folder
- /select Specifies that the directory should be selected without displaying its contents.
- /separate - Launches this explorer instance as a separate process.

Comment: this does not change how the "right click on start menu->open windows explorer" works